# Maven WebApp META-INF context.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, web-applications

I am using Maven 3 and I am trying to add META-INF folder under webapp folder. So I am trying to do the following:

```
src
 main
  webapp
   META-INF
    context.xml
   WEB-INF
```

Below is my POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.data</groupId>
<artifactId>Java-WebApp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Java-Web Application</name>

<!-- Shared version number properties-->
<properties>
<org.springframework.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>data</finalName>
</build>

<parent>
<groupId>com.data</groupId>
<artifactId>Java-Parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
</project>
```

Under src/main/resources I have added a META-INF\context.xml. When the WAR file is packaged using mvn package the structure looks like this:

```
data
 webapp
  META-INF
  WEB-INF
  index.jsp
```

The relevant files under WEB-INF can be seen. However, the META-INF folder is blank. My default Maven will add resources under the WEB-INF/classes.

I want specifically would like to have:

```
data
 webapp
  META-INF
   context.xml
  WEB-INF
```

How is this possible? I have tried other things, but still it does not work. The context.xml contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/data1"/>
```

I have tried removing the META-INF folder from src\main\resources and directly put it under webapp\META-INF. The context.xml displays but when deployed into Tomcat, the context root that I have defined does not work.

Comment: Not sure if this works, but you can try to move your `META-INF` folder to `resources/META-INF`.

Comment: So your initial problem's gone?

Comment: No, the problem still exists.

Comment: but does context.xml get to war now?

Comment: Yes, it does by removing the src\main\resources and adding META-INF folder directly under webapp. But still the context-root does not work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Put your META-INF folder within src/main/resources.

Put this on your pom.xml... sorry i missed it before;

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>


                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>

                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources
                        </directory>

                    </resource>
                </webResources>



                <warName>mywar</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

the web resources tag is what is important...
Hope this helps

Comment: This works, however in Tomcat when I load the web application the context root does not work.

Comment: this link might help you on that, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593472/define-servlet-context-in-war-file

Comment: This answer could be improved by including only the relevant code and context vs. the entire `<build />` tag if possible.

Answer (score -2):

Use the  tag instead. Above answer using  copies everything in src/main/resources to the root of your web application, which is probably not what you want to do nor an example you want to follow.

Comment: This answer is unclear and needs further explanation.