# Maven, Tomcat 7, Struts 2, Mail : javax/mail/Authenticator

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, struts2, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send confirmation email to user after he submit registration. I've read similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630002/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-mail-authenticator-whats-wrong), but as I checked I have my mail and activation jars after maven build in `WEB-INF lib` folder and I thought maybe maven doesn't see my `context.xml` file, so I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701300/maven-webapp-meta-inf-context-xml) answer and explicitly set resource files. But the problem is still exist: after client enters data and pushes submit button I'm getting exception listed below.

This is how I'm initializing my mail session in Mail utility class:

```
 public class MailUtils {
        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MailUtils.class);
        private static final Session SESSION = init();

        private static Session init() {
            Session session = null;
            try {
                Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
                session = (Session) initialContext
                        .lookup("java:comp/env/mail/Session");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOG.error("mail session lookup error", ex);
            }
            return session;
        }
     ...// utility methods
    }
```

I'm deploying my application on Tomcat 7. My `context.xml` file:

```
  <Context> 
        <Resource name="mail/Session" auth="Container" type="javax.mail.Session"
            mail.transport.protocol="smtp" mail.smtp.host="smtp.gmail.com"
            mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true" mail.smtp.port="587"
            mail.smtp.user="mymail@gmail.com" mail.smtp.auth="true"
            password="mypass" mail.smtp.ssl.trust="smtp.gmail.com" />
    </Context>
```

My `web.xml` file:

```
 <web-app >
        <resource-ref>
            <description>Magazine mail</description>
            <res-ref-name>mail/Session</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>javax.mail.Session</res-type>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
            <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
        </resource-ref>
        ...//struts filter
    </web-app>
```

This is how I'm initializing maven build `pom.xml` file:

```
          <build>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>                       
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <webResources>
                                <resource>
                                    <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources
                                    </directory>
                                </resource>
                            </webResources>
                            <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                </dependency>
             ...//other dependencies
            </dependencies>
        </project>
```

Stacktrace:

```
Struts Problem Report

Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
Messages:   

    javax.mail.Authenticator
    javax/mail/Authenticator

File:   org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/strategy/SelfFirstStrategy.java
Line number:    50
Stacktraces
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    ua.khpi.norkin.magazine.filter.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:60)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator

    org.apache.naming.factory.MailSessionFactory.getObjectInstance(MailSessionFactory.java:106)
    org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
    javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
    javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    ua.khpi.norkin.magazine.utils.MailUtils.init(MailUtils.java:37)
    ua.khpi.norkin.magazine.utils.MailUtils.(MailUtils.java:28)
    ua.khpi.norkin.magazine.action.client.RegisterClientAction.execute(RegisterClientAction.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    ua.khpi.norkin.magazine.filter.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:60)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Authenticator

    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    org.apache.naming.factory.MailSessionFactory.getObjectInstance(MailSessionFactory.java:106)
    org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
    javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
    javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    ua.khpi.norkin.magazine.utils.MailUtils.init(MailUtils.java:37)
    ua.khpi.norkin.magazine.utils.MailUtils.(MailUtils.java:28)
    ua.khpi.norkin.magazine.action.client.RegisterClientAction.execute(RegisterClientAction.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    ua.khpi.norkin.magazine.filter.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:60)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Why have you defined maven-war-plugin twice in your pom? I assume you will get warnings about that...

Comment: @khmarbaise thank you for pointing out, i edited pom.xml, but the problem is still on the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with your mail session configuration.

It's not able to find the javax.mail.Authenticator class, which means it isn't finding the JavaMail jar file.  Are you sure the jar file is being included in your war file in the lib directory?  The manifest configuration you have should be unnecessary, but I'm not sure what causes it to include dependencies in the lib directory or if it's supposed to just do that automatically.

Also, you probably want to use the [current version of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) instead of the ancient version you're using - com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.2.

Comment: yes, i'm sure i have needed jars in lib directory. also i've replaced dependency for `mail-api.jar`, as you suggested, but that doesn't help

Comment: You don't want mail-api.jar, you want javax.mail.jar.  I have no idea why Tomcat isn't seeing the classes in the jar file in the WEB-INF/lib directory since that's a Servlet spec requirement.  Perhaps there's some other Tomcat configuration problem that's causing this?  Did you try removing the manifest configuration?

Comment: i tried diff jars (mail.jar or mail-api.jar) and with and without manifest file - no success. i don't know yet where to seek the solution

Comment: You should be able to reproduce this with a trivial Servlet that uses JavaMail, such as one of the [JavaMail sample programs](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples).  If you can reproduce it using one of those, send me your war file and your project directory at javamail_ww@oracle.com and I'll look at it.

Comment: After some debugging I found that if I'm running app using `clean install tomcat7:run` then I'm getting the exception, but if I run program `Project > Run As > Run on Server` then mailing works. Do you know why i'm having such behavior ?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know.